# Как называется такой плагин? Или что это?

Tags: javascript

На главной странице, как называется такой функционал? 
Сам чувствую пока не осилю, придется плагин искать

http://www.stuartmillersolicitors.co.uk/

Comment: анимированная svg полоса, + как обычный слайдер все работает с интервалом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот эффект, когда элементы сдвигаются с различной скоростью, называется параллакс.
Я делал похожий функционал на Sequence.js: http://www.sequencejs.com/

Если у Вас не получится его настроить как надо, попробуйте http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/ он по-проще